# How to reverse iterate a linked list without using collection?

Tags: java, iteration, singly-linked-list

I'm traversing a singly linked list
e.g : 1->2->3->4->5->6>

When it reaches a position say node value 4, it has come back to previous position values like  1 or 2. How to traverse that in backward direction without using collection framework or reversing the linked list?

Comment: Is it a singly of doubly linked list?

Comment: singly linked list

Comment: @SuryaPrakash then you can't.  There is no way to do that.  Not short of, I dunno, building the new reversed linked list as you go?  But seriously, that's not a data structure that supports that operation.

Comment: How about a recursive method? The method would call itself with the next node of the list until reaching the required position. Then it would print the node and return. When the recursion unwinds, you can print the nodes in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as you do for an array, i.e., using a loop. The only thing you need are the beginning and ending indices. I have defined a method called `displayReverse()` that displays the nodes' integers between positions `a` and `b` in reverse order. *(Note: a and b indicate **positions** and NOT **indices**. That means in your case, `1` is at position `1`.)*

```
public void displayReverse(int a, int b){
    //Node t holds the node at the beginning index
    Node t = start;
    for(int i=2; i<=a; i++)
        t=t.link;

    for(int i=b; i>=a; i--){
        Node x = t;
        int s = a;
        while(s<=i && x.link != null) {
            if(s != a)
                x = x.link;
            s++;
        }
        System.out.print(x.d + " ");
    }
}
```

If you want to display from position 4 (i.e., index 3) to position 1 (i.e., index 0), you need to call

```
myLinkedList.displayReverse(1,4);
```

from the main method. In your case, the output should be

```
4 3 2 1
```

---

**EDIT**

1. If you want to do anything else than displaying it, replace the print statement in my code with the corresponding statement(s).
2. Make sure the values passed for `a` and `b` are within the index bounds of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are implementing your own singly linked list class and that it is implemented similar to this: [Singly Linked List in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82698/singly-linked-list-in-java)

Add a field to your linked list class (or extend the class) that represents a current index in your list. Lets say that at construction, that index is set to 0. Then add methods getNextObject() and getPreviousObject() that will look at the previously mentioned index, increment or decrease it, and return an object at the new index position.

**Edit**:

Please keep in mind that this is an example created without knowing your actual classes and does not check if index is out of bounds.

Lets say your LinkedList class can implement an interface:

```
public interface IMyLinkedList{
    object getObjectAt(int index);
}
```

You can create a class LinkedListTraverser like this:

```
public class LinkedListTraverser{
    private IMyLinkedList myLinkedList;
    private int internalIndex;

    public LinkedListTraverser(){
        this.internalIndex = 0;
        // your linked list class, you can pass data as constructor parameters for example
        this.myLinkedList = new LinkedList(); 
    }

    public object getObjectAt(int index){
        this.internalIndex = index;
        return myLinkedList.getObjectAt(index)
    }

    public object getNext(){
        return myLinkedList.getObjectAt(++internalIndex);
    }

    public object getPrevious(){
        return myLinkedList.getObjectAt(--internalIndex);
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate through your linked list like this:

```
LinkedListTraverser linkedListTraverser = new LinkedListTraverser();
object myObject;

while(goForward){    
    if(shouldGoForward){    
        myObject = linkedListTraverser.getNext();
    }else{
        myObject = linkedListTraverser.getPrevious();
    }

    doWorkOnObject(myObject);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LinkedList yourObject = .... ;
int desire = 4; //Enter Your Desire Digit
for(int a = 0; a < yourObject.Length; a++){
if(yourObject.get(a) == desire){
for(int b = desire; b = 0; b--){
System.Out.Println(yourObject.get(b));
 }
 break;
}
}
```

Comment: The question clearly says, "without using collections".

Comment: Good to give some code, but it should come with some explanation to point the changes and why it is the solution of the OP's question. And as progy_rock said, the OP ask without Collection, and LinkedList is part of Collection.